# django query different for mysql and sqlite and server

Tags: python, mysql, django, sqlite, django-queryset

I have a `view` where a piece of code is

```
notif = Notification.objects.get(id=self.npk, body=q, viewed=False)
            notif.viewed = True
            notif.save()
```

Here I just want to update the viewed attribute of the Notification object.

Strange thing is when I test it locally in my localhost it gives exactly what I want that it turns the notification viewed to true.

But in production it does not change the notification viewed to true. I was using SQLite in my development and thought of using MySQL in development because I am using MySQL in production.

Even after using mysql in development there is no error. It turns the notification viewed to true in development and in production it does not change.

Is it happening with me only ? Tried all the possibilities but no solution.

Same query with same database works in development but not in production. Why? Is anything wrong with server?

```
class QuestionDetailView(DetailView):

context = {}

model = Question
template_name = "question-detail.html"
def get(self, request, pk, cpk, npk, **kwargs):

    self.pk = pk
    self.cpk = cpk
    self.npk = npk
    return super(QuestionDetailView, self).get(request, pk, cpk, npk, **kwargs)

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

    context = super(QuestionDetailView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

    context['question'] = Question.objects.get(pk=self.pk, published=True)
    q = context['question']
    if self.npk:
        print "with notification"
        #Notification.objects.filter(id=self.npk, body=q, viewed=False).update(viewed=True)
        try:
            notif = Notification.objects.get(id=self.npk, body=q, viewed=False)
            notif.viewed = True
            notif.save()
        except:
            pass
    return context
```

Comment: That code will of course set the value of that object's viewed property to true, no matter what db you are using. Where are you seeing something else? Show the exact code.

Comment: do this... python manage.py shell --> Now import the required things and run the command to update the notification object. And post the logs that come on the shell.

Comment: @daniel.. Like I said I dont get any errors in the code. It works perfectly in the local but it dont works in production. I have written same code to mark the notification as view and that works perfect both on local and production just viewing the notification dont work on production. Is it because of server ?

Comment: @DanielRoseman .. I have updated the question.. If you can help me

Comment: Remove the `except: pass` block to see if it is raising an exception instead of saving it.

Comment: No, I asked you to show the code where you get that notification again to see that it is false.

Comment: @DanielRoseman.. I have checked the notification from admin that it is still false..  also view for getting all the notifications that are not viewed Notification.objects.filter(user__username=request.user).filter(viewed=False).order_by("-not_date").. It gives me the same notification which I set to viewed to true

Comment: I second the suggestion of @Selcuk.  If you remove the Except: pass code you could learn something.  Sqlite is much more forgiving with bad data  than mysql

Comment: rem;oving except pass dont give any errors. Like I said it works perfect in local just not working in production..